# Qt 101: Why can't I use this class?

Tags: c++, qt, sqlite, class

I have experience with C++ but I've never really used Qt before. I'm trying to connect to a SQLite database, so I found a tutorial [here](http://wiki.forum.nokia.com/index.php/CS001504_-_Creating_an_SQLite_database_in_Qt) and am going with that. In the QtCreator IDE, I went to Add New --> C++ Class and in the header file pasted in the header the header from that link and in the .cpp file I pasted the source. My main.cpp looks like this:

```
#include <QtGui/QApplication>
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "databasemanager.h"
#include <qlabel.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();
    DatabaseManager db();
    QLabel hello("nothing...");
    if(db.openDB()){    // Line 13

        hello.setText("Win!");
    }

    else{
        hello.setText("Lame!");
    }
    hello.resize(100, 30);

    hello.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

And I'm getting this error:

```
main.cpp:13: error: request for member 'openDB' in 'db', which is of non-class type 'DatabaseManager()'
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction? I know "copypaste" code isn't good, I just wanted to see if I could get DB connectivity working and I figured something like this would be simple... thanks for the help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change the DatabaseManager line to:

```
DatabaseManager db;
```

You're declaring a local function called `db` that takes no parameters and returns a `DatabaseManager` object when you provide the `()`;

Comment: Tried this earlier and ended up with:
main.cpp:11: undefined reference to `DatabaseManager::DatabaseManager(QObject*)'

Comment: That looks like a link error.  Make sure you're linking in the QT library.

Comment: Its not a link error, its saying there is no constructor defined for those arguments.

Comment: I'm sorry, what exactly do you mean by linking in the QT library? I have included my header file in main.cpp. Do I have to do something special in QtCreator to link? I'm just doing Build All.

Comment: Excellent, adding a constructor and destructor in my source file fixed the errors. Having other logical problems (it thinks it's opening the db but the db doesn't exist...) but I'll give that a whack on my own. Thanks to all of you!

Comment: (+1) Thanks RC. I made the same mistake with query. Initially it was query(someDB), then I deleted "someDB" but forgot the "()" - and next thing you see is error in every line with query. :D Thanks again!